# Expose global singletons to CSharpScripts

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to use the Roslyn Scripting Engine to provide a scripting engine for 
our Software. Our software exposes some of it's api as singletons. However i cannot access those statics in the executed code.

For example i want to do something like this in script:

```
IOManager.Instance.DoWork(...);
```

When i do this:

```
var scriptContent = "IOManager.Instance.DoWork(...);
var options = ScriptOptions.Default;
options.AddReference(this.GetType().Assembly);
var script = CSharpScript.Create(scriptContent, options);
await script.RunAsync();
```

I get this error:

```
 The name 'IOManager' does not exist in the current context
```

I thought maybe adding a reference to the current assembly might fix this problem. But it doesn't. I also know, that it is possible to set a global object to the script context. But i want to expose all statics/singletons accessible where i execute the script, to the script itself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably need to include the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the import for `IOManager` in your script:

```
var script = CSharpScript.Create( "IOManager.Instance.DoWork(...)" , ScriptOptions.Default.AddImports( "Namespace for IOManager" ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem indeed.